# When should the assignment operator return const T &, T & or T?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

According to this [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/), the assignment operator can have one of the following forms:

```
(1) MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& rhs );
(2) MyClass& operator=( MyClass& rhs );
(3) MyClass& operator=( MyClass rhs );
(4) const MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& rhs );
(5) const MyClass& operator=( MyClass& rhs );
(6) const MyClass& operator=( MyClass rhs );
(7) MyClass operator=( const MyClass& rhs );
(8) MyClass operator=( MyClass& rhs );
(9) MyClass operator=( MyClass rhs );
```

- The forms (2), (5) and (8) are discouraged because an assignment operator should not modify its parameter. I cannot think of a case where this is necessary.
- The forms (3), (6) and (9) are useful for the copy-swap idiom.
- I take it that (7)-(9) should only be used for const-objects (which do not change after constructing). Is that correct?

My question is: When should I use which return type `MyClass`, `MyClass &` or `const MyClass &`?

Comment: (2), (5), (8) are necessary to implement something like "move semantic".

Comment: From [this canonical assignment operator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator): "The canonical copy-assignment operator is expected ... to return the lhs by reference". Also, a *copy* assignment operator should not modify its rhs, so it should be preferably be a reference to a constant. Although passing by value can be useful sometimes (as seen in the previously linked reference).

Comment: @Scheff No, you're thinking of `operator=( MyClass && )`. The question has `operator=( MyClass & )`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No. I think of assignment where the source has to be modified (e.g. like in std::uniqueptr). I believe I once did this (in exceptional cases) before `T&&` even existed...

Comment: That reference has been updated last in 2010. I suggest that you find something newer.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not just outdated, but wrong. The assignment operator (member `operator=`) can be overloaded for multiple types, not just the class type itself, and the return type isn't restricted at all.

As a matter of style, returning a non-const reference to the object is common for consistency with built-in types, but I personally prefer `void`. This makes it (almost) impossible to use assignment expressions as sub-expressions, as in `a=b && c=d`. I consider this an advantage.

As the comments note, C++11 added move operations, so you should consider whether `void MyClass::operator=(MyClass&&)` is beneficial to you.